# Correcting division by zero in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my **SQLite** statement below there is a problem with division by zero in the case `count(t2.ref_id)` is zero.

Could I adjust the **SQLite** statement so that if the `count(t2.ref_id)` is zero the scarsity (scarsity factor) will be higher than the highest non-zero scarsity?

```
select t1.id, cast(:totalItems as float) / count(t2.ref_id) as scarsity
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.ref_id
group by t1.id
order by scarsity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the value 0 and do something different.  One common way is to divide by `NULL` as many SQL varieties have `NULLIF()` to turn a value into a `NULL` instead.

```
select t1.id, cast(:totalItems as float) / NULLIF(count(t2.ref_id), 0) as scarsity
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.ref_id
group by t1.id
order by scarsity
```

But I'm not sure that SQLite has `NULLIF()`, so you could use the more long winded `CASE` version instead...

```
select t1.id, cast(:totalItems as float) / CASE WHEN count(t2.ref_id) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE count(t2.ref_id) END as scarsity
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.ref_id
group by t1.id
order by scarsity
```

The `COUNT()` won't be calculated twice even though you typed it twice.  The value will be re-used :)

Alternatively, do something completely different if you get 0 rows...

```
select t1.id, CASE WHEN count(t2.ref_id) = 0 THEN 9999999 ELSE cast(:totalItems as float) / count(t2.ref_id) END as scarsity
from t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.ref_id
group by t1.id
order by scarsity
```

Then you can check for NULLs as being the highest value, or just check for 9999999, etc, etc.

Comment: Looks good but what is the result of division *totalItems / null*? Is it high number? I need the scarsity high (maximum possible) because there are 0 occurences.

Comment: @xralf - Any calculation involving NULL yields NULL.  `9 + NULL = NULL`, `9 / NULL = NULL`, etc.  So your subsequent logic should treat `NULL` as `maximum scarcity`.  If that's not possible, use the other version and code in the scarcity you want to use.

Comment: In sqlite `x/0 = NULL`, so `x/0 = x/NULLIF(0,0) = x/NULL`